# HID reports/scan codes for RN 42 HID's gamepad profile

Tags: bluetooth

i'm creating a bluetooth HID gamepad with a arduino leonardo and the RN 42 HID module.

I can actually use the module to iterate a keyboard or a mouse but i didn't understand how to

send the right scan codes to iterate a gamepad or a joystick.

In the user's guide of the module they said that the raw report had to be sent like that:

```
0xFD,0x06,Buttons 0-7,Buttons 8-15,X1,Y1,X2,Y2
```

Any idea on how to set the report?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to init a `SoftwareSerial` instance.
Then you have to enter *Command Mode* of the RN-42 module with a sequence of *$$$*, set up the HID joystick mode (SH, 0240) and *name the device* (SN, ...), set the *baud rate* (SU, ...), etc.
After the successful initialization of the module, you can send HID joystick reports as follows:

```cpp
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothRX, bluetoothTX);
//...

// Command Mode
// --------------
bluetooth.begin(9600);
delay(50); 
bluetooth.print("$$$");
delay(50); 
bluetooth.print("SN,HIDJoystick\r\n");
delay(50); 
bluetooth.print(" SU,57\r\n");
delay(50); 
bluetooth.print("S~,6\r\n");
delay(600); 
bluetooth.print("SH,0240\r\n");
delay(200); 
bluetooth.print("R,1\r\n");  
delay(400);

// HID Joystick Report
// --------------
bluetooth.write((byte)0xFD); //Start HID Report
bluetooth.write((byte)0x6);  //Length byte

// 1. X/Y-Axis
bluetooth.write(45);  //First X coordinate
bluetooth.write(-33); //First Y coordinate

// 2. X/Y-Axis
bluetooth.write(45);  //Second X coordinate
bluetooth.write(-33); //Second Y coordinate

// Buttons
bluetooth.write(B10000001); // Second Byte (Buttons 1-8)
bluetooth.write(B10000000); // Second Byte (Buttons 9-16)
```

Please note that the buttons are controlled via binary values.